# Python & Neo4j & JSON - For each user create NODE

Tags: python, json, neo4j

I want to develop a python script which perform the following:

1. Load json UsersFile
2. for User in UsersFile, create a node

```
## example of User
{'UserName': 'lolipop', 'UserId': '544', 'groups': ['winners', 'losers']}
```

3. I tired something like, (but I getting errors):

```
import json
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

uri = "neo4j://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "123"))

UsersFile = json.loads(open("users.json", "r").read())

def create_user_node(tx, User):
    tx.run("CREATE (n:User $Usercxt);", Usercxt=json.dumps(User))

for User in UsersFile ['Users']:
    with driver.session() as session:
        session.write_transaction(create_user_node, User)
```

Error:

```
neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Type mismatch for parameter 'Usercxt': expected Map, Node or Relationship but was String (line 1, column 16 (offset: 15))
"CREATE (n:User $Usercxt);"
                ^}
```

What do you recommend to do at this point?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is a syntax error. You should format your input file per column and NOT Json like format. There is no shortcut.

Change the code as below (as an example of user, thrn add more column names for other columns)

```
 Old: for User in UsersFile ['Users']:
 New: 
 For context in UsersFile ['Users']:
     User = context.user
```

Because you want to pass the usercxt value and not the json string {Usercxt: "sample usercxt"}

Then change this too

```
  Old: tx.run("CREATE (n:User $Usercxt);", Usercxt=json.dumps(User))

 New: tx.run("CREATE (n:User {usercxt: $Usercxt});", Usercxt=User)
```

The reason is you cannot use a json like formatted string when creating a node. It is NOT doing a string replacement when you do this: $Usercxt -> {usercxt: "sample usercxt"}.

The syntax stays the same as below

```
 Create (:Label {prop: value})
```

Hope this helps.